# How many horses can I have?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

Can you have more than 3 horses stabled, or is that all the horses we get? Or can we have 3 stabled and 1 to ride?

I would like to have all the superior horses if possible, but if not I'm going to have to pick my favorite 3 and go with those.

Comment: I'm not far into the game so I've been to the one stable. If there's more stables then you should be able to store more horses there I'd imagine.

Answer (score 7):

According to manual, found in the RDR2 Companion app. You can keep up to three horses in stables.

Manual text:

> There are stables in most major towns, shown by a blip on your map and Radar. At a stable >you can:
>
> - Buy and sell horses.
> - Retrieve your lost horse.
> - Rename your horse.
> - Buy Horse Care items such as food, snacks, and tonics.
> - Buy or upgrade equipment such as saddles, saddlebags, stirrups, horns, blankets and bedrolls.
> - **Keep up to three Horses safely in stables.**
> - Customize your Horse's appearance and accessories.

RDR2 Companion app manual:

[image]

Comment: You can also have a temporary horse altho this will not stick around forever unlike the others

Answer (score 2):

You can have 4 horses total 3 in the stable and one you ride around on

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this you can [edit] in that 3 is the max in the stable?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to have 6. 3 in stable my main horse and both my “temporary” horses which I was able to manage through bonding

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know I could have 2 temporary horse!!!

Comment: So just a word of caution here... you got your main horse and the first temporary horse.  Once you grab another temporary horse, the first one will follow you, but any type of cut scene will cause that horse and any skins that were on it to vanish.