# What are the different types of horse breeds?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

As a follow up of [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/340483/how-many-horses-can-i-have) question I was wondering.

What are the different type of horse breeds in rdr2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.gtabase.com/red-dead-redemption-2/animals/horse-breeds/) website: There are **19 breeds** of horses that can be found across the lands of Red Dead Redemption 2, each of which handles differently with its own defined characteristics.

> 1. American Paint Horse, *Work Horse*
> 2. American Standardbred, *Race Horse*
> 3. Andalusian Horse, *War Horse*
> 4. Appaloosa, *Work Horse*
> 5. Arabian Horse, *Superior Horse*
> 6. Ardennes, *War Horse*
> 7. Belgian Draft Horse, *Draft Horse*
> 8. Dutch Warmblood, *Work Horse*
> 9. Hungarian Halfbred, *War Horse*
> 10. Kentucky Saddler, *Riding Horse*
> 11. Missouri Fox Trotter, *Race Horse, Work Horse*
> 12. Morgan Horse, *Riding Horse*
> 13. Mustang, *War Horse, Work Horse*
> 14. Nokota Horse, *Race Horse*
> 15. Shire Horse, *Draft Horse*
> 16. Suffolk Punch Horse, *Draft Horse*
> 17. Tennessee Walker, *Riding Horse*
> 18. Thoroughbred, *Race Horse*
> 19. Turkoman Horse, *Race Horse, War Horse*